# How to serialize object in ASP.NET Core/6 using a camelCase?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.text.json, jsonserializer, asp.net-core-6.0

When using ASP.NET Core/6 to return object as JSON we use `return Ok(data)` which takes the `data` object and serialize it using camelCase.

But, what I want to serialize an object manually, it does not serialize using camelCase.

Here is how I am attempting to decentralize the object

```
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data)
```

Is there a service to use in ASP.NET Core that would serialize the object using the default formatter? IS not, how can I serialize using camelCase?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0#use-camel-case-for-all-json-property-names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the object: JsonSerializerOptions. You have to pass it as a parameter after your object like this:

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
};

System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, options);
```